# pushState not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JS function that has pushState in on a click event...

```
 $wrap.on( "click", ".page-link", function( event ) {

    event.preventDefault();

    if ( window.location === this.href ) {
        return;
    }

    var pageTitle = ( this.title ) ? this.title : this.textContent;
        pageTitle = ( this.getAttribute( "rel" ) === "home" ) ? pageTitle : pageTitle + " — Site";

    History.pushState( null, pageTitle, this.href );

} );
```

Only nothing is happening, the URL remains the same - has anybody worked with this before and know what's happening?

Comment: What browser are you using and what version? IE supports it only starting at 11, other browsers also didn't support it in old versions. (see [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=history))

Answer (score 0):

There's no function called `History.pushState()`; what you're probably wanting instead is [`history.pushState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries).

Comment: @Liam Have you looked for errors in your browser's console?

Comment: Yeah, nothing is thrown up

Comment: @Liam hmm I can't reproduce your problems, I've tried running your code and the URL does change for me..

Comment: @Liam Do the links in [this codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PWVwKZ) work for you? (It's basically just your code, and it works as it should for me). If they do, then there's probably something happening in your case outside of the code you've posted here...